# UITableViewCells will not populate from my NSArray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

When I run my app, the UITableViewCells are blank. I am trying to fill them with the content from "NSArray sortedArray", which lists dates in descending order.

NSLog (@"sorted array is %@ and the count is %lu while string at first index is %@", sortedArray, (unsigned long)[sortedArray count], indexed);

NSLOG OUTPUT:

2017-02-13 09:50:15.693 test[22349:7300081] sorted array is (
    "02/11/2017",
    "01/25/2017",
    "01/17/2017",
    "12/25/2016",
    "12/17/2016",
    "11/25/2016",
    "11/23/2016",
    "11/17/2016",
    "10/11/2016",
    "10/06/2016",
    "08/08/2016",
    "08/05/2016",
    "08/01/2016",
    "07/28/2016",
    "07/15/2016",
    "07/13/2016",
    "07/11/2016",
    "07/08/2016",
    "06/17/2016",
    "05/17/2016",
    "02/18/2016",
    "01/18/2016",
    "12/18/2015",
    "11/18/2015",
    "10/18/2015",
    "09/18/2015",
    "08/18/2015",
    "07/18/2015",
    "06/18/2015",
    "05/22/2015",
    "04/17/2015",
    "03/17/2015",
    "02/17/2015",
    "01/17/2015"
) and the count is 34 while string at first index is 02/11/2017

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *strSessionID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                          stringForKey:@"sessionID"];

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/get_statement_list?session_id=%@",
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"serverName"], strSessionID];


NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aURL];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];    NSArray *jsonArray = [dict objectForKey:@"statements"];
NSMutableArray *pdfs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *sortedArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<[jsonArray count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary* dates = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *MM=[dates objectForKey:@"month"];
    NSString *DD=[dates objectForKey:@"day"];
    NSString *YY=[dates objectForKey:@"year"];
    NSString *iDates = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@/%@", MM, DD, YY];
    [pdfs addObject:iDates];
}

//put in descending date order
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
sortedArray = [pdfs sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString
*obj1, NSString *obj2) {
    NSDate *d1 = [df dateFromString: obj1];
    NSDate *d2 = [df dateFromString: obj2];
    return [d2 compare: d1];
}];

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
   (NSInteger)section
{
return [sortedArray count];

} 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
}

NSString *statements = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


cell.textLabel.text = statements;

return cell;
}
```

Why won't my tableview cells populate with the objects in sortedArray? How do I fix this?

Comment: pls show complete code. Dont show pieces of code.

Comment: try `[tableview reloadData]` when array allready filled - may be your array fill to late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up the tableview in the Interface Builder, did you connect the datasource and delegate to this class. Like shown in the picture[image].

Drag with ctrl pressed from table view to the File's Owner. [image].

In case you have provided your tableview programmatically, then you have to make the connection in code.

Comment: Yes, i already have connected the delegate and datasource in the interface builder. :/

Comment: try to set a Breakpoint on the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method to check, if method get called. If not, maybe the delegate protocol UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource is missing.

Comment: My issue is solved. Made the table a property instead of an instance variable. Referred to the NSArray by "self.sortedArray", and ultimately [tableview reloadData] worked! thanks! @Daivest